# Definir o tamanho de um campo na migração

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como faço para definir o tamanho de um campo do tipo string em uma migration? Ex:

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :rooms do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.string :location
  t.text :description

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

Como posso dizer que o campo title é varchar(50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o parâmetro `limit`:

```
t.string :title, limit: 50
```

Documentação oficial aqui: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#column-modifiers